# Passing an integer pointer to a constructor and getting runtime memory error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a vector of a class-name vertex. The value of "n" is not known at compile-time so I'll be using new to create to create the "path" array. But the problem occurs when I create the input array in a function and push it in the vector.

```
int n;
class vertex {
public:
    int *path;
    int visited = 0;
    vertex(int *y) {
        path = new int(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            path[i] = y[i];
    }
};
void inp(vector<vertex> graph) {
    int t1[] = { 0,1,0,0 };
    int t2[] = { 0,0,1,0 };
    int t3[] = { 0,0,0,1 };
    int t4[] = { 0,0,0,0 };
    graph.push_back(vertex(t1));
    graph.push_back(vertex(t2));
    graph.push_back(vertex(t3));
    graph.push_back(vertex(t4));
}
int main() {
    n=4;
    vector<vertex> graph;
    inp(graph);
    _getch();
}
```

For simplicity I've created t1 to t4 as static arrays. But still it shows some error at runtime

Comment: Try `void inp(const vector<vertex>& graph)` and see if that works.

Comment: now it doesn't let me push_back into the vector (beacuse of const I think)

Comment: how about without const then?

Comment: What were the original errors you were getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:try use: `path = new int [n]`, rather than  `path = new int(n)`;

2:if you want to push elements to graph, you should change your function `inp` to `void inp(vector<vertex>& graph)`